# Can I find Lightroom Publish Collections with photos pending Publication?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3

Lightroom's publish collections allow one to publish photos to various places by simply adding a photo into the appropriate collection.  In this example, I use SmugMug, and I have my various SmugMug galleries setup so that they show under my SmugMug publish collection.  When I want to add a photo to my Seattle gallery, I drag it there.  When I want to add a photo to my Portland gallery, I drag it over there.  And so on.

My current practice is that I don't always go and publish a gallery as soon as I add a photo.  Is there a way to have Lightroom easily show me those publish collection galleries which have pending updates?

Answer (score 1):

I have never found one. I resort to having all collections in a service under a top-level one, which I call 'All', and at least then I can just click on each 'All' and do republish (rather than having to click on each collection.)

In my opinion Lightroom's Publish setup is good but not yet great if you are a 'power user.'